# How do I determine if a character is within a range in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, character

I'm trying to write a function that checks if a character is within a certain hexadecimal range.

I'm trying the code shown below:

```
(def current \s)
(and (>= current (char 0x20)) (<= current (char 0xD7FF)))
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Character cannot be cast to 
java.lang.Number (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
```

I assume because the >= operator expects a number, it tries to type cast it.In regular java, I could just do:

```
(current >= 0x20) && (current <= 0xD7FF)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

explicitly convert it to an int first

```
(<= 0x20 (int current) 0xD7FF)
```

Answer (score 3):

Chars aren't numbers in Clojure though it's easy to cast them into characters with the `int` function.

```
(number? \a)       => false
(number? 42)       => true
(number? (int \a)) => true
```

For casts to primitive types you can use the function with the name of the type you want (see `(find-doc #"Coerce")`).

```
(int (char 0x20))
(float ...)
(map double [1 2 3 4])
 ....
```